# Using arrays with loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Good day to everyone,
I have multiple pages and I want to loop them all into individual arrays, but I couldn't. Thanks in advance to those who will help.

```
Option Explicit
Dim d1() As Variant, d2() As Variant, d3() As Variant, d4() As Variant, d5() As Variant, d6() As Variant
Dim d7() As Variant, d8() As Variant, d9() As Variant, d10() As Variant, d11() As Variant, d12() As Variant
Dim personel As Collection, sonuc() As Variant

Sub examples()
Dim i As Integer
d1 = Sheet1.Range("A4:AX34")
d2 = Sheet2.Range("A4:AX34")
d3 = Sheet3.Range("A4:AX34")
d4 = Sheet4.Range("A4:AX34")
d5 = Sheet5.Range("A4:AX34")
d6 = Sheet6.Range("A4:AX34")
d7 = Sheet7.Range("A4:AX34")
d8 = Sheet8.Range("A4:AX34")
d9 = Sheet9.Range("A4:AX34")
d10 = Sheet10.Range("A4:AX34")
d11 = Sheet11.Range("A4:AX34")
d12 = Sheet12.Range("A4:AX34")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an error? Is there a question? This might be an XY problem, where you try to solve something in one way while there is a much simpler way that currently cannot be determined due to lack of context (information). Also, we most probably need an explanation of what you plan to do with this (a continuation of the code or the code of another procedure where you utilize the populated variables). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71544787/edit) at any time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but based on your code, it looks as though you could use help converting what you have written using 12 variables into code that uses one array.  Here is the simplest conversion of your existing code to use a single array instead of many variables:

```
Option Explicit
Dim d(12) As Variant

Sub example1()
    d(1) = Sheet1.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(2) = Sheet2.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(3) = Sheet3.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(4) = Sheet4.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(5) = Sheet5.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(6) = Sheet6.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(7) = Sheet7.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(8) = Sheet8.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(9) = Sheet9.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(10) = Sheet10.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(11) = Sheet11.Range("A4:AX34")
    d(12) = Sheet12.Range("A4:AX34")
End Sub
```

However, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not sure what it means to just assign a variant to a range.  If you are trying to have each variable (or element of the array) refer to the range on each sheet, then you'll need to use the "set" keyword to bind a variable (or element of an array) to an object.  In this case, it's slightly more efficient to declare the array of the "range" type instead of variant as follows.  I've added a loop to print the value from the first row, third column in the range on each sheet (which is cell C4 on the sheet) for demonstration purposes.

```
Option Explicit
Dim d(12) As Range

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    Set d(1) = Sheet1.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(2) = Sheet2.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(3) = Sheet3.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(4) = Sheet4.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(5) = Sheet5.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(6) = Sheet6.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(7) = Sheet7.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(8) = Sheet8.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(9) = Sheet9.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(10) = Sheet10.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(11) = Sheet11.Range("A4:AX34")
    Set d(12) = Sheet12.Range("A4:AX34")

    For i = 1 To 12
        Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

This code is a bit longer than I would like it to be but to refer to each sheet by its object name, that what we have to do.  **If sheet names have a pattern similar to the code names, we can shorten the code significantly:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim d(12) As Range

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 12
       Set d(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A4:AX34")
       Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

An important thing about Arrays in VBA is that they start counting at 0 instead of 1.  So in all of the examples above, we have an unused element of the array at the very beginngin.  We can issue a compiler directive (Option Base 1) atop the code to tell the VBA interpreter to start arrays counting at 1 as follows:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
Dim d(12) As Range

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 12
       Set d(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A4:AX34")
       Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

However, I think it is more commonly done to allow the arrays to count from zero and just offset the array index as needed as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim d(11) As Range

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To 11
       Set d(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i + 1).Range("A4:AX34")
       Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This is all fine, but we often do not know the number of elements we need in the array before the code runs.  To make the size of the array dynamic, we declare the array without specifying a size and use the ReDim statement to set its size at runtime (notice the empty parentheses when the array is delclared, and the use of the "Ubound" statement in the For Loop to find the upper boundry of the array):

```
Option Explicit
Dim d() As Range

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim d(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(d)
       Set d(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i + 1).Range("A4:AX34")
       Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Finally, I see from the original code posting that you are familiar with collections.  Because a collection is an object with properties and methods, it may be simpler to use a collection instead of an array, which is just a memory allocation scheme.

```
Option Explicit
Dim d As New Collection

Sub example1()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       d.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A4:AX34")
       Debug.Print d(i).Cells(1, 3).Address, d(i).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Notice here that collections start counting at 1.

Comment: FYI you can specify the lower bound when you Dim an array `Dim d(1 To 12) As Range`

Comment: Dear Gove,
Each page represents a month of the year. Staff salaries are available on every page (ie every month). I want to see the personnel data on these pages as a total on one page. But the staff is not stable during the months. For this reason, I need to do some operations. Since it would be slow in terms of speed, I wanted to do the operations within the arrays instead of copying this data to a page and performing the operations there. What I actually want to do and learn. We can navigate through the pages in a loop. Do the same with arrays.

Comment: @MurtiCom, That makes a bit more sense.  let's do this:  Accept this answer and write a new question with more details.  We need to know how the sheets are named (e.g. January, February, etc.) .  Also, show the strucure of the data in the month sheets, be sure to indicate how to identify when the employee is the same from sheet to sheet  and what needs to be aggregated across months.  Once that is posted, indicate that in a comment here and I'll take a look.  It sounds like a pretty straightforward problem, once it's explained in detail.